# Split images of different classes into training and testing sets in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python, but I want to implement deep learning tools in python. I have collected a set of images of different classes or categories. My work is to perform image categorization using convolutional networks. The first step is to split the these images into two sets for training and testing. Then I will load these images and do some preprocessing before feeding them into networks. I am now only curious on the first part.

I post my work for this:

```
import numpy as np
from os import listdir

def getPaths(rootPath):
    folderList = listdir(rootPath)
    imgPaths = []
    categories = []
    for folders in folderList:
    imgPath = os.path.join(rootPath,folders)
    imgPaths.append(imgPath)
    categories.append(folders)
    return (imgPaths, categories)

def getImgPaths(rootPath, p):    
temp = getPaths(rootPath)
folderPaths, categories = temp

trainImgPaths = []
trainLabels = []
testImgPaths = []
testLabels = []
for ii in range(len(folderPaths)):
    temp2 = getPaths(folderPaths[ii])
    imgPaths = temp2[0]
    randIdx = np.random.permutation(len(imgPaths))
    trainIdx = randIdx[:int(p*len(imgPaths))]
    testIdx = [idx for idx in randIdx if not idx in trainIdx]
    trainPaths = [imgPaths[kk] for kk in trainIdx]
    testPaths = [imgPaths[kk] for kk in testIdx]
    trainCat = [categories[ii] for jj in xrange(len(trainPaths))]
    testCat = [categories[ii] for jj in xrange(len(testPaths))] 

    trainImgPaths.extend(trainPaths)
    testImgPaths.extend(testPaths)
    trainLabels.extend(trainCat)
    testLabels.extend(testCat)
    return (trainImgPaths, trainLabels, testImgPaths, testLabels)
```

The code can work but it seems cumbersome somewhat.

Comment: What did you try ? Or do you want us to do your assignment ?

Comment: I just want to code two functions. I can implement these in Matlab, but have some trouble in python.

Comment: What are the troubles encountered ? Show us what you've tried !

Comment: do you need stratification or random sampling would work?

Comment: @MMF: I will post my work later

Comment: @jingweimo ok, I'll be able to help you then

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You've just defined a problem and seem to be expecting people to solve it for you. Also... You need to do some reading on k-fold cross-validation. You don't want a distinct training/test sets. Pick a fraction of the training set and use it to test a classifier built with the rest of the training set, then repeat using different documents to test. It will require a number of passes to evaluate properly, but it will reduce variability introduced by the selection of the test set.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os, random

def getImagePaths(imgroot, cats, pot):  # please excuse the naming
    trainImagePaths = []
    testImagePaths = []
    trainlabels = []
    testlabels = []
    for cat in cats:
        files = os.listdir(os.path.join(imgroot, cat))
        split = int(pot*len(files))
        trainImagePaths.extend(files[:split])
        testImagePths.extend(files[split:]
        trainlabels.extend([cat]*split)
        testlabels.extend([cat]*len(files)-split)

    # optionally, shuffle

    return trainImagePaths, testImagePaths, trainlabels, testLabels
```